# Why does the Intent that starts my activity not contain the extras data I put in the Intent I sent to startActivity()?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I explained this badly originally. This is my question: The Intent I send to the startActivity() method, contains a private field, mMap, which is a Map containing the strings I sent to putExtra().  When the target activity starts, a call to getIntent() returns an Intent that **does not** contain those values.  The mMap field is **null**. Obviously, something in the bowels of the View hierarchy or the part of the OS that started the new activity created a new Intent to pass to it, since the object IDs are different.

But why? And why are the putData() values not carried fowrard to the new Intent?

The activity that starts the new activity extends Activity. Here's the startup code:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(final MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case 4:
        i = new Intent(this, StatList.class);
        i.putExtra("Name1", "Test1");
        i.putExtra("Name3", "Test2");
        startActivity(i);
     }   
 }
```

I've tried the key values with and without the (recommended) complete package name prefix.

In the Eclipse debugger, I have verified the values for the player names are being inserted into i.mExtras.mMap properly.

Here's the code from the startee:

```
public class StatList extends ListActivity {
private final StatsListAdapter statsAdapter;

public StatList() {
    statsAdapter = StatsListAdapter.getInstance(this);
} // default ctor

@Override
public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    final Intent i = getIntent();
    final Bundle extras = i.getExtras();
          < more code here >
}
```

When execution gets to this method, mIntent.mExtras.mMap is **null**, and mIntent.mExtras.mParcelledData now contains some values that don't look sensible (it was **null** when startActivity() was called). getIntent() returns mIntent.

I've also tried startActivityForResult(), with the same result.

From the docs and the samples I've seen online & in the sample apps, this should be easy. I've found another way to meet my immediate need, but I'd like to know if anyone can help me understand why something this simple doesn't work.

Comment: Why are you using the "final" keyword for the OnCreate savedinstance state bundle, and other variables?

Comment: have you tried String test = i.getStringExtra("Name1"); to see what the result is?

Comment: Your question is inconsistent - you show code using `Intents` called `i` but then you talk about `mIntent.mExtras.mMap` (for example) which doesn't exist in your code snippets. Which is it?

Comment: mIntent is the field in Activity that holds the Intent used to start the activity. I looked at it with the debugger inspection facility. mExtras is the field in an Intent that holds the extras. mMap is the field in an Extras that holds the Map with the extra values.

Comment: The field that holds the extras object is null when it gets to StatList.onCreate, although it held my values in the mMap object when I called startActivity

Comment: It seems that we are missing code in order to help. You reference `mMap` & `mIntent` yet you don't show them in the OP. Can you show us these and how they are implemented in your code? How you're trying to extract the extras, etc. If you don't show the code relevant to your issue we can only guess.

Comment: @Asok the `mIntent` and `mMapp` are part of the core `Activity` class so they are not instantiated in his code. I have same problem I create an  Intent, add extras and start new Activity but when I arrive on the new Activity my data is lost, simply null. No solution so far.

Answer (score 2):

In your main Activity:

```
i = new Intent(this, StatList.class);
i.putExtra("Name1", "Test1");
i.putExtra("Name3", "Test2");
startActivity(i);
```

Then in `StatList.class`

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
String name1 = extras.getString("Name1");
String name3 = extras.getString("Name3");
Log.i("StatList", "Name1 = " + name1 + " && Name3 = " + name3)
```

Comment: No. The map in the Extras object that should hold the values is null. getString() fails.

Answer (score 0):

Update the following two line

final Intent i = getIntent();
final Bundle extras = i.getExtras();

Replace it with

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if(extras!= null){
String var1= extras.getString("Name1");
String var2= extras.getString("Name2");
}
```

Comment: getString() fails with null pointer exception. because the field (mIntent.mExtras.mMap) that should hold the map of values is null.