# How to send data to new Android activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I am working on an application that gathers user selection (from a checkbox) and sends it to a new activity (when a button is pressed ). In the new activity, a new data will be collected (editText) and the received data + newly collected data will be combined and sent via email.

When I press the first button to send the checkbox data to the new activity, I get an error:

> The application has stopped unexpectedly

Here is the code:

```
 public void onClick(View v) 
{

                   cakeDataformated();
                   // to convert the data (checkBox) to a string
                   String fianlformatedData = cakeDataformated();

                    Intent i = new Intent(this, PersonData.class);  
                    i.putExtra("cakedata", fianlformatedData);
                    startActivity(i);

    }
```

and the check box conversion method is:

```
 public String cakeDataformated () {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    boolean checkyStatus1 = checky1.isChecked();
    boolean checkyStatus2 = checky2.isChecked();
    boolean checkyStatus3 = checky3.isChecked();
    boolean checkyStatus4 = checky4.isChecked();
            // to read the checkbox data
    String form = finalFormUsingFollowing (checkyStatus1 ,checkyStatus2 ,checkyStatus3 , checkyStatus4 );
        //  to convert the check box response into a message and save it as 
            //  a string called form
            // example : cakes selected are : cake1 , cake3 
    return form ;


}
```

So, if there are any errors please tell me.

Comment: Check out LogCat for the exact error message. That should tell you where to find the origin of the problem.

Comment: In `PersonData` how are you retrieving the data? You might check this link to compare: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13485382/1134705

Comment: Why this line ' cakeDataformated();'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) this
            .findViewById(R.id.radio_group);
    radioGroup
            .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int id) {
                    final RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton) radioGroup
                            .findViewById(id);

                    String selectedText = radioButton.getText().toString();
                    Intent i = new Intent(this, PersonData.class);
                    i.putExtra("cakedata", selectedText);
                    startActivity(i);
                }

            });
```