# can someone give me an example how to use this radiogroup code? android

Tags: android

actually it's the second line I'm not too sure how this indexOfChild work

```
RadioGroup rg = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
int rbIndex = rg.indexOfChild(findViewById(rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId())
);
```

Sorry if this is a dumb question.

Comment: This is an [example][1] on RadioGroup


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13595476/how-to-send-data-to-new-android-activity/19613729#19613729

Answer (score 0):

`getCheckedRadioButtonId` returns the id of the selected button in the group, or -1 if there is none selected.

`indexOfChild` returns the integer value of where the radio button is within the radio group, or -1 if the view does not exist in the group.

So all together, you are first checking to see if a radio button is selected.  If there is a button selected its id is returned.  Then you check to see where in the group the selected button is, 1, 2, 3, etc.

Comment: humm...yup that's easy to understand but if for the code I pasted above, how/where I can implement an easy code like setTitle then the indexOfChild so when I click any of the radio buttons my title will be changed to that 1,2,3, or etc.  more of a visual person easier for me to understand more and the way of using it seeing it visually:(